# Functions Returns Boolean in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, boolean, return-value

I use PS Remoting , Powershell 2.0.

I need call to Functions that returns boolean value ($true or $false).

My function:

```
Function TryDisableClientForCredSSP()
{
    try 
    {
        WriteTrace "[TryDisableClientForCredSSP]. Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client "
        $script=Convert-StringToScriptBlock("Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client ")
        Caller($script)

        WriteTrace "[TryDisableClientForCredSSP]. winrm get winrm/config/client/auth [($env:COMPUTERNAME)]"
        $script=Convert-StringToScriptBlock("winrm get winrm/config/client/auth")
        Caller($script);

        return $true;
    }
    catch 
    {
        Write-Verbose "[TryDisableClientForCredSSP] Error "
        Write-Verbose $_
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message`r`n
        return $false;
    }   
}
```

note: WriteTrace  function just only do Write-Host.

I use it:

```
    $ok = TryDisableClientForCredSSP;
    WriteTrace   "[TryDisableClientForCredSSP]. $ok"
    if ($ok -eq $true)
    {
        WriteTrace "[TryDisableClientForCredSSP]. OK true"
    }
    else
    {
        WriteTrace "[TryDisableClientForCredSSP]. KO false"
    }
```

I get this output:

```
[TryDisableClientForCredSSP]. Auth     Basic = true     Digest = true     Kerberos = true     Negotiate = true     Certificate = true     CredSSP = false  True
[TryDisableClientForCredSSP]. OK true
```

I want that this line outputs "[TryDisableClientForCredSSP]. True"

```
 WriteTrace   "[TryDisableClientForCredSSP]. $ok"
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Functions return whatever each command spits out to the output stream.  Try eliminating that output like so:

```
    [void]WriteTrace "[TryDisableClientForCredSSP]. Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client "
    $script=Convert-StringToScriptBlock("Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client ")
    [void]Caller($script)

    [void]WriteTrace "[TryDisableClientForCredSSP]. winrm get winrm/config/client/auth [($env:COMPUTERNAME)]"
    $script=Convert-StringToScriptBlock("winrm get winrm/config/client/auth")
    [void]Caller($script);

    return $true;
```

Comment: And if you don't like using [void], you can add `| out-null` to those lines instead.

Comment: Isn't there a more simple way to stop output, such as using a semicolon after a command?

Comment: There are three ways: [void]...,  ... | Out-Null and ... > $null.  That's it.

Comment: Any sample for three ways in your answer it would be great, I think.